# Xamarin.forms: Is it possible to use Grid on RelativeLayout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

This is my 3rd day in Xamarin classes and I am really struggling with setting a responsive app background. I am trying to have this structure:

[image]

I finally achieve to set a responsive background with `AspectFill` property which is standing between `<RelativeLayout>` tags.

But now, I am unable to have the label on the top center of the app due to the `<RelativeLayout>` tags. The label which I have created for the logo stands on the left side.

I tried to add `HorizontalOptions` property, but unfortunately, it hasn't affected.

Here are the related `xaml` codes:

```
<RelativeLayout Padding="0">
    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="background.png" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
    </Image>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="">
            <Label Text="MENU">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Text="LOGO" FontSize="28">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My failed result:

[image]

Do we have any other alternatives for the `<RelativeLayout>` which causes a lot of UI problems?

Comment: in this scenario, I'm not sure why you need RelativeLayout at all - it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  That said, are you sure your Grid is filling it's container horizontally?  Try setting it to Fill, and then use a 3 col grid 25/50/25

Comment: the Page itself has a BackgroundImage, or you can assign it as a child of the grid and use the col/row span properties to make it extend

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate a navigation bar manually? You could simply use the NavigationPage already provided by xamarin forms, which takes care of creating a menu button and the page title.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage?view=xamarin-forms

Here you find a more practical tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Jason

The problem has been fixed by adding a new column grid. In other words, there should be 3 columns in total. But, I had added only 2 columns.

Here are my updated `xaml` codes:

```
<RelativeLayout Padding="0">
        <!-- Background -->
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="background.png" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
        </Image>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                </ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*">
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*">
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                <Label Text="MENU">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <Label Text="LOGO" FontSize="28">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </RelativeLayout>
```